# Request times out when applying terraform plan on AWS, or describing instances through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, terraform

I am having an issue accessing the following endpoint from an EC2 instance located in a private subnet.

Architecture is the following:

- VPC

  - Private Subnet 1 (there is a route on 0.0.0.0/0 to Transit Gateway)
  - Private Subnet 2 (there is a route on 0.0.0.0/0 to Transit Gateway)
  - Transit Gateway
  - NACL for both subnets is allowing all ingress and egress ports.

I got the following issue when attempting to run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`

```
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: ---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: POST / HTTP/1.1
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: Host: ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.30.16 (go1.13.7; linux; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.1
2.24 (+https://www.terraform.io)
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: Content-Length: 87
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: Authorization: ............ SNIP .................
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: X-Amz-Date: 20200506T132216Z
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4:
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: Action=DescribeAccountAttributes&AttributeName.1=supported-platforms&Version=2016-11-15
2020-05-06T13:22:16.123Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-05-06T13:22:46.124Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: 2020/05/06 13:22:46 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Send Request ec2/DescribeAccountAttributes
failed, attempt 0/25, error RequestError: send request failed
2020-05-06T13:22:46.124Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: caused by: Post https://ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 10.0.19.205:443: i/o time
out
2020-05-06T13:22:46.166Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: 2020/05/06 13:22:46 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Retrying Request ec2/DescribeAccountAttribu
tes, attempt 1
2020-05-06T13:22:46.166Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: 2020/05/06 13:22:46 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request ec2/DescribeAccountAttributes Detai
ls:
2020-05-06T13:22:46.166Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.60.0_x4: ---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----
```

I got the exact same issue when running `aws ec2 describe-instances` from AWS CLI. Times out.

**Notes**

1. I am working in a federated AWS context through AWS SSO.
2. I created an IAM user for terraform so we do not have to constantly refresh the SSO token, so it's not a token expiration issue.
3. I was able to install tools from Internet on the EC2 instance (Docker, Git, Terraform, etc.)
4. AMI is `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200408 (ami-0edd51cc29813e254)`
5. I am able to list S3 buckets using `aws s3 ls`.
6. I used the latest version of Terraform and AWS CLI.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check CloudTrail to see if the command is getting through and if it has an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is "my EC2 server in a private subnet can't reach the AWS EC2 endpoint".

The EC2 endpoint is on the internet, and resources in private subnets typically have no public IP or route to the internet, so this is expected behaviour. Does your private subnet have a route to access the internet? NAT gateway or NAT instance are the standard options.

You can alternately use an [EC2 VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/interface-vpc-endpoints.html). These have a small cost, but are basically a shortcut from your VPC to the resource you need across the AWS backbone.

Beware though, you may need multiple endpoints, and they're not free. My best guess (it's not really clear) is the cost is they're the same as a [PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/pricing/) endpoint, currently $0.01c/hr in us-east-1. In my current project I need about 7 endpoints and it worked out cheaper to use a NAT gateway.